# how to change the position of the button in perl tk?

Tags: perl

```
$mw->Checkbutton(-text => "FAU_GEN1.1 ", -command => sub{faugen1=1} )->pack;
```

This command creates a check button at the centre. How do I shift it to a certain position ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the geometry manager methods.  Start with [the User Guide](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl/Tk#The_packer_-_grouping_with_Frame_widgets), then you might want to check out [grid](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tk%3a%3agrid), [form](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tk%3a%3aform), [pack](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tk%3a%3apack), and [place](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tk%3a%3aplace).